# Pandas: Difficulty Filling in Null Values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the [Kaggle Titanic dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data) and trying to fill in null values.  Running this:

```
combined_df.isnull().sum()
```

Get me this:

```
Age            263
Embarked         2
Fare             1
Parch            0
PassengerId      0
Pclass           0
Sex              0
SibSp            0
Survived       418
fam_size         0
Title            0
dtype: int64
```

So I do the following to fill in null values:

```
combined_df.Age.fillna(combined_df.Age.mean(), inplace=True)
combined_df.Embarked.fillna(combined_df.Embarked.mode(), inplace=True)
combined_df.Fare.fillna(combined_df.Fare.mean(), inplace=True)
```

So when I run this now:

```
combined_df.isnull().sum()
```

I get:

```
Age              0
Embarked         2
Fare             0
Parch            0
PassengerId      0
Pclass           0
Sex              0
SibSp            0
Survived       418
fam_size         0
Title            0
dtype: int64
```

So it handles the `Age` and `Fare` columns correctly but `Embarked` still has two null values as before.

Interestingly, when I run:

```
combined_df.Embarked.value_counts()
```

I get back:

```
S    914
C    270
Q    123
Name: Embarked, dtype: int64
```

So that makes it seem like there *aren't* any null values in `Embarked`?

Very confused; any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `combined_df.Embarked.mode()` return? Are you sure it's a scalar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the value returned by `mode` to fill as it is a Series object (well you can, but that signifies which indices to fill). Instead use the first entry (it is possible there is a tie).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Emb': ['S', 'Q', 'C',  np.nan, 'Q', None]})
df
    Emb
0     S
1     Q
2     C
3   NaN
4     Q
5  None
df.fillna(df.Emb.mode())
    Emb
0     S
1     Q
2     C
3   NaN
4     Q
5  None
df.fillna(df.Emb.mode()[0])
  Emb
0   S
1   Q
2   C
3   Q
4   Q
5   Q
```

For more clarification:

```
mode = df.Emb.mode()
mode
0    Q
dtype: object
0      S
1      Q
2      C
3    NaN
4      Q
5    NaN
Name: Emb, dtype: object
mode.index = [5]
5    Q
dtype: object
df.Emb.fillna(mode)
0      S
1      Q
2      C
3    NaN
4      Q
5      Q
Name: Emb, dtype: object
```

Comment: And the reason it doesn't work is that it looks for alignment in the Series returned by `df['Embarked'].mode()` Since that Series only have index 0 in your example, it would fill only index 0 in the actual DataFrame. That's already not-null so it does not have any effect.

Answer (score 2):

pass `dropna=False` into `value_counts`

```
combined_df.Embarked.value_counts(dropna=False)
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Good answer. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) actually states `Excludes NA values by default.`

Comment: @Wen Helpful but I still don't know why my code doesn't properly fill in null values in the `Embarked` column

Comment: @bclayman  mode will return the serise , fillna need a value not serise , you can add .values at the end

Comment: @bclayman also , you can see the document https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html  Always returns Series even if only one value is returned.